# Finding change of coordinates matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $Q$ be the unknown $2\times 2$ change of coordinates matrix, from $b$ to $B$. 
Let the $2\times 2$ matrix $b$, be the basis for vector space $V$ in $\mathbb R^2$. 
Let the $2\times 2$ matrix $B$, be another basis for the same vector space $V$ in $\mathbb R^2$.

Now my book shows to find $Q$, you set $B = (b)(Q)$ then you solve for $Q$. 
Whats driving me crazy is that when I try it with $B=(Q)(b)$ I get a different answer. 
I know matrix multiplication is not commutative but I don't think that should make my answer incorrect, only different.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$. This has a representation $x$ in the basis $b$ and a representation $y$ in the basis $B$. Then we have $v= b x = B y$.

To find the change of coordinates from $b$ to $B$, we want to find $y$ when given $x$. In this case we see that $y = B^{-1}b x = Qx$.

Comment: thanks, I could not have asked for a better answer